# Function condition based on array length

Tags: php

The title might sound... trivial, but i had no idea how to name this problem in one sentence.

I have different arrays of variables in different places in my file(s)
for example:

```
//set1:
$a =1;$b=2;$c=3;$d=4;$e=5;
$set1 =array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);
//set2:
$x=1;$y=2;
$set2 =array($x,$y);
```

Im tryin' to write a function which makes different operations based on array length.

For (simplified) example, in first case I wanna execute:

```
if($set1[0]){/*something*/}
if($set1[0] || $set1[1]){}
if($set1[0] || $set1[1] || $set1[2]){}
if($set1[0] || $set1[1] || $set1[2] || $set1[3]){}
if($set1[0] || $set1[1] || $set1[2] || $set1[3] || $set1[4]){}
```

In second case, I wanna execute

```
if($set2[0]){}
if($set2[0] || $set2[1]){}
```

I tried to write function using eval(), and it works...

```
function _f($array)
{
    $i =-1;
    $x =count($array);
    $str ='';
    $str2 ='';
    while(++$i < $x)
    {
        if($i ==0){
            $str .="\$array[$i]";
        } else { 
            $str .=" || \$array[$i]";
        }

        $str2 .="if(".$str."){\n echo 'lol'; \n}\n\n";
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    echo $str2;
    echo "</pre>";

    eval($str2);
}

_f($set1);
//output: lollollollollol (as I expected)
```

...but is that solution safe when user can set the variables? Are there better solutions?

Comment: please read the content

Comment: Are the empty `{}` parentheses also intended to contain code?

Comment: yes, but this will be simple operations like multiplications based on values in input array

Comment: But basically something like `/*something*/`.

Comment: In fact, your program will output nothing until it encounters the first `true` value. After that, the whole boolean expression will evaluate to `true`. It is hard to tell from your code, because in fact your array contain only true values, and for that you could use a simple `str_repeat('lol', count($array))`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what the intention of your program is because of the limitations of the input data, as mentioned in comment above (all `$array` entries evaluate to `true`).

But the following sequence, which would replace your loop, would produce the same result as the `eval`s:

```
$status = false;
while(++$i < $x) {
    $status = $status || $array[$i];
    if ($status) echo 'lol';
}
```